# how to create correct preg_replace pattern?

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

I have these urls in my magento store:
charogh/product/1298/productname
the productname will be change for each product,the correct structure is:
charogh/product/[0-9]+/[a-zA-z0-9]+

I should change and replace 'product/[0-9]+/' with '' and make the url to 'charogh/' when user enter this url 
'charogh/product/[0-9]+/'
and do not replace it when user enter this url
'charogh/product/[0-9]+/productname'
how can i do it with preg_replace or preg_match?

I use this pattern but it replace in both structures
$header=preg_replace('//charogh/product/[0-9]+/',"charogh",$header);

thanks for your help!

Comment: Try `'/\/charogh\/product\/[0-9]+\/?$/'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you anchor  the match at the string end with the `$` anchor:

```
'/\/charogh\/product\/[0-9]+\/?$/'
```

This way you will prevent matching strings that contain more data after 1+ digits.

Also, the `\/?` at the end allows matching 1 or 0 `/` symbols (i.e. the `/` is optional).